# libGDX: How to properly load screens into memory?

Tags: java, performance, memory, libgdx

I have a splash/loadingscreen when my game is started. At first, I'm loading my assets using the [AssetManager](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html) and after that, I want to load my [Screens](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Screen.html) into memory. Currently, that's how I do it:

```
menuState = new MenuState(game);
playState = new PlayState(game);
gameOverState = new GameOverState(game);
```

Now I want to show the MenuState with a fadeIn and fadeOut Animation. This works fine, but the progress of this animation is based on the current delta. For the next few render calls I got such a high delta, that there is no visible animation at all.

I don't understand, why there is a high delta not only for the next render call (loading all these states takes time, but when they are done loading there is nothing to do anymore) but also for the next few render calls.

How to load these screens that delta is low after loading them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During your animation which takes `delta` into account, you could introduce a "maximum" delta. This will help, so that your animation isn't skipped, but it may still appear a bit laggy at first.

A similar method is used in the `LibGDX` source code for `Stage.java`

```
public void act () {
    act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
}

public void act (float delta) {
    //does stuff
}
```

`Math.min` will take the smaller value, of either `deltaTime` or `1/30f` - to guarantee that it will update in small increments even if every frame is actually taking a long time.